# curl php curl_exec return an encoded result

Tags: php, html, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to get an url by this code:

```
<?
    $url='http://www.lacapital.com.ar/secciones/laciudad.html';
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But $result give me this:

> ‹í}Ëw¹ÑïZú+0ÌwL*æ[oÉÒ\Š¢m%²¤+J“L||tÀnl»ÙàôC–<ñq·w—e³øNvÙÜs>ýc·ªôƒ‰¢%&‰“±ÙÝ@¡P¨*üPx½únÿ¸yöãI‹õÃËNÎ÷š,WªTþ´Ü¬TöÏöÙŸßž½;dµr•ùÜœÐ‘w+•ÖQŽåúa8ÜªT>þ\þ¼\–~¯rvZ¹BZ5Ì¬–ÂTÎ²Ú¹ÝÅWTàÕÀõ‚ dj›››*7¥Ü†B'tÅî!gM'²¹ÍþÊð7:!w™-Ø©¸ïHx$CÇrxPdÜ
>
> ## î:˜üš…ÒæÌåÌñºÒpËy!¹…bÛKg¿Æ$¾è%__UTÑ‹¯"äÙ-‰Ÿ"çr'×”^(¼°tv=9f©§(®Â
>
> ²¿Í¬>÷îœŸ½.mäXå6*‡ÜëE¼—¦$‚RãtJ6_t}ôS©×ªÕTZ^ûN¯æât/,x¹ÍêÕZí;Tí”,ÛeÖ(³3iË€¹ðŸ-|aõá”&üKïË¬-ØPø'(¯(t\çKF¤¡DZ’
>   ¹mA-„Ä¸¾pT+ÂÉâJfAùž-‘b7NEy¬:¶,ß¢6%Ï?p‹çGKý$®?KßR²†<–X‘ùšRÑ&aYÀ=ÈÛEî÷
>   µãñ"óbÇÙ)2ËåÓu,”n‘    ÛI3ë† { ñ"Ò² d9â²(/3´FkSÄúYd4@9°„§˜”CÇK§J×4
>   pÊérìŠ ( Þr`>sV.DÐV“jÃ ÎÂGÁ@‡‘Ï±B‘•­°@g û
>   ú(|V¾àêS„Å‰Mè;¼p7²‹xRtm(¹a@Ô  Û’À 
>   /…åx(»P8*íXý,Ð=õÅV(}$$<+N°U”„¸'Q±i;ðÙCYC{pE@¸ë
>   Ë“®ì¥%â…¾Ýp¶J0¦ºoŽß¶öŽÏRZttÜ8m¾=ø¡UdGÇÇû'c™ÞµFs@2L­3²±,íÃóÓ“THûãþÁ)£"NöSySY‡¾„j‡×;9ÙÛ"—2¯_Áé¢ ²‰¼e]ígÑ¾Eä¦%|7•:ÕÕ¸\›ot¨ÌýÊ4a
>   ù”lŠÎ!of2ç&guYo~[ñÁuš[H;¯àÛ°¸¼¬|
>   $óEtVF¾ß‰tP”  3C¯7±ÝÎ·Ž—ö_µ*ü©­®®®UkµÍ•b­¾²\[]ß¨­kÕµõµÍõêF±V[¯®UW
>   ÕTÂÃá…c§¯ÔêµÕj}µ^[Y¯ÖkÓÄšqäêÉÙäâCì¾ÀO¥XçQ(§ñëJ‹»Ù®ùâ°q{ê-îB)GòµÚ”oñ•ëxŸ€aw'GíyøVŽõ¡cB]IxúÒAnÌ±°Q•.¿Äç2ü5šÚÞ¥PFV¿”É3úJ›-«¸´:¬T½n*g„àþX[¹Z[¹›j
>   úMÎPT4p¾À›«ëW«ë÷,òÌYÞzýj½~Ïò(ÏœåÕj+Wðß=KÔ¹æ-sr¯Ü»L•K—¹øê»R‰5Ûm¶ÇÁJ¥¬r†×
>   ë}!ÂÃ>@£l+§Fý3pêº1÷4 S    „e7*ITt`ç½Óe­ð
>   ¼Uºèü’«·Àü%÷™`;¬ãŽ¸Ü˜ø/plø;²pYÜƒE›Cõ\ÁqÇ
>   Š]§ù¢Ø•œEG;øOÏ—Ñ°8àþ§"
>   ¼þÂ¯¿,Ê(FaüM*8²Ð‹§/¡<™[*C×    ùb~i{\&+
>   ƒÎNu›9¯DÙ^/ìÃï—/—ØÏ‹¶´"„’eËà¬Z®À§‚xï|€ì__UT=Q&ï…g;ÝØ:ªÁþð'vâòkqÔb·Ê‰ƒK´£¶\_ÞX_[†^¢¶9ÚbÜ'oì„Öe§ôRmöþÿyHE—?¹Ý4—ÀI"`]ÖýkÄƒv¯ü#¿*÷¤ì¹ô’
>   ¡w×é€F|îÊÎGo¥^®'OXÚ4EH˜P\´J Ïs¼Þ8÷UR¨°jj÷áá
>   ÕGðÖ§QF¦éså÷Úº¹ß8k¼g¿¯~_ôøO
>   âôÏ_ÿÊÞØ^Äßåaôïó0ÎmX–Œ¼0_dùóFiy}¹¶¹±YªåQFÓîËw¼#@V˜|¬—£<ð'“-Ä:œ@wvéˆÏ*E¡ydTeä³ÇË):W5³€de¬=¤ÍÔ?OypíYð5ô#±½/
>   ÑÐÂó¨;ÁVží¤JÁ™(ƒY†Ò’.ûžé„•Jžm©ü½Ä^²<Œ-Â Ü+Û2êÀhÆYŸÊž+¶
>   ›ß¦jéZôD¨«ì]ŸñŠ-©Ìûê‡m”a¬
>   Ž¤-ÊöŒì   °}QèÁˆ%@K^*ÀßÐ´>ìb£Ž(Êbà_n±hÃÙRP[^=!ýiKÁÏjÞ¦ÖdPÊ¶È®@}‡nHO¹.2ö3(sD#‚ÒJm3Ÿq43å€I„ˆ
>   ËØY€¯ð¨4øgÄ)ÜË3­-ƒOª­/¯.oÎa¦=~Ð”Â‚Ñ]\ÖFøÊªÈÖâ«Ž´¯)`\áBD±¶KæØÀ-ÿ$ä¥ð/à¾¯À¿ÚÍ½æ–èHù‰µ÷ÿ¨šÈdêvJ>ô)X¦J®KNÆµ€¼†ÃêÜGxî~$Í›¬ré¤†Ž±N³w}`€Ôt×0<÷0&”µ@PDøPvløæØ*™6­\„ëyèb»ºZdµ+Ð½ƒwÕíÜÚÀ%öÎèhéA¦š‚®
>   CÁxmHðË\úö§üÒÒö¨;=ûì„Ð³?ÄÚ“6ÝïRâ Š ‘Ÿ´h¡àÛåºàtßM+PY
>   ìcÒ¤ Ï”&ýVºœF¨8&»øìØ@=@eÄÔwÈJ‰jákZZ9m2Åœ¦[úÄ Ù¨ qÄ°zÁ¤
>   ƒ7'›p¾§œ©BÁÅ4äç¯Û‹    $ð1ê»à7ìÆ¿ýÁ|Js§KZ,cŸÏ–ŸËÝÎ)àhlÓ
>   ¤¾4°8€:ÁÇLÄàO¥BÕea_°×{ìm´Oúòz¯Œ_
>   *c¤Çê'¸Â}Jáì³®/DŸ÷Öt$÷mML§Ð@¸ç¾‹„pà8ô¦¯9µ½NQÆÐ´¢ÜToØkâÄ«’MÝ2FÖ‘ç¨^M—½VhVQDÃêëñ#LÈ©SEChc¬é÷:·VåˆÑÜà¿
>   €R$€á>k—ŸÙ5øT†Qgh|iƒ
>   ¨,Ç'¯ÀRÄ© †|g~½÷î…¼0`)ì;|è    •õ+ê·i²†më‰ŠQeµÀ:Xc
>   ÆÆ!à¨Ö%˜;,ñÎ€õ$°Þ¾X4
>   M)ÊAÔAÍêˆBŽØÝDÊµÞÄ£>èXa\•2HIÆ•´ËÝ@ ]W*5øû¿
>   9lx`†‚[ý,XZXXÀÿÐÈ2‘´À©üW…´¤Ca œðþê@­
>   à™ÉÜ™”yRâÌ7(ó%d…O_6Öøfu¦“þ±ïv˜¹®®6}£„hÒÓb9ìiµo.PyIÂ'2]f|çWJ©¿ÆúocBÖCÉmÒ70ß|ÀTÏÈôû¾ôd¸×*åß
>   %W6o‹NÔc ¶¨¤4®#Pe8ÿR¸×ðþ‘Ca3îÙl€4LÑÁ@`íFJX
>   hC‹0D@"ÑBO©³ÀtÝ`”¦`†–‹,Ñc(¥[†@Ì.i‡d`uÐ£Ýa èNG@ªÈMÇ    ?k 
>   ä>,¤àz
>   3àï,:×îÂÞÅy»Ba‚—À5Ñ÷š~åÀqärˆÎsªs$šPÝ[±|'…ai8Qù=Qü}EÙãÒÒÄÞÇÕÓ};9DmC§éŸSaèîK+54ØfúõáaâèU»†-Ü½²(ÅCGE~[gjø=êW™sðz«V~ØŠ‡Æv0’©’+^Â÷•\18ØÊ‰ÎúFƒ[959+Šƒ`ë½~ºØ\­^­V%èçÚFõj­zñ–âÉëåjõª¾ZmŒ½Ù{ÓLÞ¬Á›Zµšû€–jTëÓD[i‡Ü•‡#õ3ƒ(ø®Üž‰Ö¤¿
>   /ÀÔNËëÂ’v’JQµª¡Ç
>   dõ‰R#(ha’OQ„Ô‹²¡hRq0&€.†MN³æ«=d“>7ìv_~.à´U&Ûûàƒ*pšùK³œ®Ì6y{øšâ_óyxh`{Òƒà§ïbFpˆ2’Fé]»®~ØVfÐM¹úb9øÅÛ±ÅÕq·k¶[§?´NwrK¦$H^¾TÓ"€Ç—;¬VÕD–B~;óu‰¨1Êm’ê5Q»®Þa?>ÓëAi_(÷oÔáàõ-Qƒƒ×§w­<å€”ÚÏäyGFáVläS~I(•‘®8]Cê5Î~Ð¤‡}ÌáC_`O`ž(æ©ä«Ã«|úµNªÞ¶è‹íÛÉ{0Ö†<™F,Þ´Ðì;®]€vÕZ½”#q.f……Ãx8ÿ2o_Ãsò‹òç5QË•PÝ·‰”¨÷ÙVk7ONÎ°ó0=C…Áã{øo%¸ý|…B‰c+­ÔTFWhLpA¬¸ß­´ÄÊ¼`Ê`”Ÿ ÎVô¬ÊJe}ƒoæ•Of$ˆµØtÆM4ŒáGdÖu¶EØ°ßNìÑ¯¼ŽýçH®¥Øs˜dìV…G¼ú€¸oqÔÕAú6Ž1

Comment: where is code?? By the way, I'm not the down voter!!

Comment: As @ShaunakShukla points out, you should add the code/command that you execute. Also, that binary response is not very useful, at least without context. You should add the expected output.

Comment: As @MarianoD'Ascanio points out, you should add expected output. because, you haven't pass any values to URL and URL you've written here, is opening in browser, means it's reaturning whole webpage! So make it clear that what do you expect from code!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried you code and yes it is garbled. One this to point out is, you can also add an option `CURLOPT_ENCODING` in `curl`. Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.lacapital.com.ar/secciones/laciudad.html';
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); // add this one

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Note: As @Akshay suggested, this also works well.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip'); // add this one
```

Comment: or probably this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");